# media player seek bar with service

Tags: android, service, seekbar

i have a media player and
 this is the seekbar code  in activity class

> ```
>    public void updateProgressBar() {
>     mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
> }
> private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
>     public void run() {
>         long totalDuration = mService.getDur();
>         long currentDuration = mService.getPosn();
> ```

```
        // Displaying Total Duration time
        start.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        end.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        Log.d("Progress", ""+totalDuration);
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}


@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}


@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mService.getDur();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(mService.getPosn(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
   mService.seek(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

and i called this on oncreate method

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

but doesnt show the current duration and when touch seek bar this error shows :

> ```
>  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.music.Gramofone.Playmusic.onStopTrackingTouch
> ```

i dont know where is my mistake

Edit : 
this my handler

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

and this is part of my service :

> private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

```
/**
 * Class used for the client Binder. Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public
        // methods
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}


public int getPosn(){
    return mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDur(){
    return mPlayer.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPng(){
    return mPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public void pausePlayer(){
    mPlayer.pause();
}

public void seek(int posn){
    mPlayer.seekTo(posn);
}
```

and i bind service in activity too

Comment: Show full stacktrace

Comment: Do you initialize the mHandler object?

Comment: Can you say where your service code is?

Comment: edited see the question again :)

Comment: and what is different between this way and use mediacontroller ? can i use mediacontroller in this case ?